# The Swiftblade full round action contradiction

Tags: dnd-3.5e, actions, prestige-class

So, I recently read the Swiftblade prestige class on the wizards website. However, one thing there caught my eye:

> Perpetual Options (Ex): At 9th level, you can perform even more actions with the haste spell. Instead of making one extra attack at your highest base attack bonus while under the effect of a haste spell that you cast yourself, you now have the choice of making one extra move action or one extra standard action. For example, you could make three consecutive move actions with this ability, two move actions and one standard action, one move action and two standard actions, **a full attack action and a move action, a full attack action and a standard action, a full round action and a move action, or a full round action and a standard action.**

*([Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210817000115/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/prc/20070327), emphasis mine)*

However, I believe this to be against the standard rules, in reference both to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/23071/do-two-standard-actions-equal-a-full-round-action) and the Players handbook, which says:

> Full-Round Action:A full-round action consumes all your effort during a round. The only movement you can take during a full-round action is a 5-foot step before, during, or after the action.

*(Player's Handbook, page 139)*

Am I right, and this class has been made carelessly? Or is this outside the normal rules? How should I treat this?

Comment: Generally speaking, in D&D's rules the specific beats the general. So, the *general* rule is that "A full-round action consumes all your effort during a round", but in the *specific* case where a lvl9 Swiftblade uses haste, that rule is overruled by the description of Perpetual Options.

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/23071/do-two-standard-actions-equal-a-full-round-action

Answer (score 14, accepted):

D&D is a game of exceptions.

You must use your Str modifier to hit with a melee weapon, unless you're wielding a light weapon and you have the Weapon Finesse feat.

Weapon Finesse only works with light weapons, but there are some weapons that explicitly work as if they were light only for Weapon Finesse purposes (like the rapier).

Your full round action takes up all of your turn **except** if you're a lvl 9 Swiftblade with *haste*.

Since the *Perpetual Options haste* adds a standard action to your turn and a complete action is a move+standard*, now you have a move action and two standard ones and you can combine a move and a standard action to get a full round action.

---

*There's a little bit of educated guesswork here. In 3e, you could forfeit a move action and a standard action to get a complete action, that could even be split between two consecutive rounds. In 3.5e the wording has changed to "takes up all your action", implying that no matter how may actions get added to your turn, a full round action eats them all.
At the light of the Swiftblade wording, I think RAI on full round action is that, since a round is made of move+standard, the 3.5e manual just wanted to simplify things by saying "all your actions" instead of naming them.
Even if this is not held true, Swiftblade still clearly states this as an exception and *specific trumps general*.

Comment: A good answer, but the fact that a full round action ISN'T a combined move action and a standard action is what inspired my question.

Comment: @Zachiel I agree with kravaros; treating a full round action as a combination of a move and standard is the only flaw in this answer (things would be much simpler if it were defined in those terms, but alas). You hit the nail on the head otherwise; full round actions take up all your actions _except_ when Haste says you get to have one more on top of that. You already have my upvote but I think you should take another look at how you can express that bit.

Comment: I've added a note. Please tell me if it convinced you.

Answer (score 7):

The [Haste spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/haste.htm) seems to be a special exception in this circumstance. The regular version explicitly grants an extra attack *in addition to* a full attack, which is a full-round action.

This *Perpetual Options*-upgraded Haste permits you to perform a move/standard action explicitly in addition to a full-round action or full attack, which would normally use up your entire turn.

(Then again, perhaps I was wrong in that other question!)